# Write and execute Java Script or JQuery with SharePoint 2013 Reusable workflow for Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have to get the n number of users  from the list and compare with the document library item-users, So is it possible to write Java-script or JQuery in Workflow for Office 365 online ? If Yes then how?
Thanks Ram.

Comment: It isn't possible to use JavaScript in a workflow but its possible to call REST api inside the workflow. So maybe you can start from that.

Comment: Hello Akhoy,
I'd tried with REST and not getting,
I have to change the permissions of a particular document from Document      Library ?

Comment: That is possible. http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-(Item-Level-Permissions)

Comment: I'd already tried this one, Did you implemented this one to achieve the same or any idea ?